# jSP form Query Parameters

Tags: html, jsp, forms, post, get

While using an HTML form on a jsp page, the data/values automatically get picked up on submit and a url gets generated: nextPage.do?param1=value1&param2=value2

Is there a way to change the generated url without redirecting again: nextPage.do?q={param1=value1$param2=value2}.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use JavaScript to handle the form submission, extract the parameters, and transform them. But be careful about special characters : what if some parameter value has a dollar sign inside? I wonder why you want to do that.